# How to check what user has in clipboard?

Tags: javascript

In my project I have this function which copies to the clipboard after the user has clicked the button.

```
copy(id) {
      const input = document.querySelector(`#${id}`)
      input.setAttribute('type', 'text')
      input.select()
      document.execCommand('copy')
      input.setAttribute('type', 'hidden')

      if (id === 'wallet') {
        this.walletCopied = true
      } else if (id === 'amount') {
        this.amountCopied = true
      }
    }
```

The if-else construct is needed in order to change the icons if the user has already copied them. Is there an opportunity to check what the user has in the clipboard, because I may need it further to change the icons again if the user has changed something in the clipboard

Comment: I can't see that this has anything to do with node or express?

Comment: There’s no `document` object in express. Don’t confuse JavaScript code you send to the browser and run there with other JavaScript code that you run on the server with Node.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the answer is easy. User can have only one string copied in clipboard. So, we can do something like that:

```
copy(id) {
  const input = document.querySelector(`#${id}`)
  input.setAttribute('type', 'text')
  input.select()
  document.execCommand('copy')
  input.setAttribute('type', 'hidden')

  if (id === 'wallet') {
    this.walletCopied = true
    this.amountCopied = false
  } else if (id === 'amount') {
    this.amountCopied = true
    this.walletCopied = false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

document.execCommand() invoke the text copy and keep at the buffer. This is something environment-specific. To know the content you can write the code to spawn the process. For OSx we use:-

```
    var proc = require('child_process').spawn('pbcopy'); 
    // Note:- pbcopy is availalbe in osx
    proc.stdin.write(data); 
    proc.stdin.end();
```

However, for windows, it will be different. If you want to go more sophisticated solution then you can use clipboardy.

https://github.com/sindresorhus/clipboardy